# Android or iOS navigation app that gives an alert when close to a speed camera in South Korea

Tags: android, ios, maps, car

I am looking for Android or iOS application that can give me an alert whenever I am close to a speed camera in South Korea when driving. My only requirement is that the application misses as few speed cameras as possible. It's OK if the application focuses on static speed cameras only or mobile speed cameras only: I am fine using multiple applications concurrently.

Comment: A few Koreans I know uses [Waze](https://www.waze.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Kakao Navi](http://www.kakao.com/services/67) (카카오내비):

- Free of charge
- gives an alert whenever the driver is close to a static speed camera in South Korea. I believe that it was 100% accurate over the 2000 km I drove.
- gives an alert whenever the driver is in a speed controlled area.
- can record the video in background

[image]

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.locnall.KimGiSa&hl=en